# Connection refused when requesting Deno server (with oak middleware) from NextJS api routes

Tags: next.js, cors, deno, oak

I'm trying to request Deno server from next api routes. To simplify (with the same result), let's assume we have server written with oak middleware like:

```
import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'
import { oakCors } from 'https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts'

const app = new Application()

app.use(
  oakCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
  })
)

app.use((ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = 'Hello World!'
})

await app.listen({ port: 3001 });
```

oakCors are added to alow cors from http://localhost:3000, where next app will be running.
Let's run simple next app where in the /page/api/test.js a request to http://localhost:3001 is implemented:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3001')
    console.log(data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  res.json({ done: true })
}
```

So, now if we render 2 buttons:

```
<button onClick={() => fetch('http://localhost:3001')}>direct fetch</button>
<button onClick={() => fetch('api/test')}>fetch by api routes</button>
```

Where the first button requests http://localhost:3001 directly, and the second one requests test api route (which in turn requests http://localhost:3001).

In the first case (direct fetch) everything is ok.
In the second case, there is an error in the next server console:

```
error - unhandledRejection: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14062:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3001
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3001
  }
}
```

**Question: why connection is refused in the second case and how to fix it?**

*Additionally: If a ngrok tunnel is run for http://localhost:3001*

```
ngrok http 3001
```

*requests work through this tunnel in both cases (using generated tunnel url).*